# Ошибка. Или нет?

Tags: android, android-manifest

Почему вот это в манифесте выделяется ошибкой, хотя компилируется и работает все правильно ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ошибки, найденные IDE не всегда являются ошибками компиляции.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По факту это не является критической ошибкой, это я думаю и так понятно из того что приложение компилируется и запускается. Просто гугл пытается как мне кажется насильно заставить разработчиков добавить поддержку необходимых им сенсоров ориентации. Чтобы убрать предупреждение, можно под строкой `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` добавить такую строку:

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

и внутри `application` добавить:

```
tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity"
```

так же есть такие варианты как добавить полную поддержку ориентации или не указывать явно:

```
android:screenOrientation="fullSensor" / android:screenOrientation="unspecified"
```